# cin does not flush cout when using stream iterators

Tags: c++, stream

I am trying the following code,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
ostream_iterator<string> oo(cout);
istream_iterator<string> ii(cin);
istream_iterator<string> eos;
int main()
{
    **oo = "Some string ..\n";
    string s1 = *ii;
    cout << s1; 
    return 0;
}
```

It first asks for input, and then prints the output, opposite to what was expected.

How come?

Comment: What did you expect, and why did you expect that?

Comment: I guess you never got the hint when it told you that "problem" is not allowed in titles...

Comment: I'm still struggling to think of a legitimate reason to *ever* use an `ostream_iterator<>`, or `istream_iterator<>`, in the fashion being demonstrated here.

Comment: Uh, this is a perfectly valid question. The program should be equivalent to `std::cout << "Some string\n"; std::string s1; std::cin >> s1;` but he says it isn't printing the prompt first. Don't blame him for making the example brief, and self-contained.

Comment: @WhozCraig i was trying out stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Standard, C++11 §24.6.1/1,

> After it is constructed, and every time ++ is used, the iterator reads and stores a value of T.

So it's actually prompting you for input before `main` is entered, when the global variable is initialized. Moving the declaration of `ii` to the second line of `main` fixes the problem.